# Why is mkdir() no executing on MySQL UDF running in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, mysql-udf

I plan to create a log file for my UDF which will be located in `/var/log` directory. So I call `mkdire("/var/log/my_func",...)` on the C code but after calling the function from Mysql and **ls**, the directory is not created.

My main aim is to log UDF errors, I would also appreciate any tips on how I can log UDF errors to a file.

Here is the code sample:

```
struct stat sb;
if(stat("/var/log/my_log_dir", &sb) != 0 || !S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
    mkdir("/var/log/my_log_dir", S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH|S_IXOTH);
```

My function return an integer, so when I comment **mkdir** and return a random int the returned value show on MySQL

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `mkdir`? We can't effectively help without seeing your code so please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At a guess you are running as a user that doesn't have write access to `/var/log`.

Comment: Check my updated question. When I run the code I dont get any errors. The function works fine except mkdir on the system

Comment: FWIW, `S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH|S_IXOTH` is a really ugly and unreadable way to write `0755`. The standard guarantees the values match the familiar octal numbers so it's far more readable just to use them.

Comment: And how about my other comments? Check the return value of `mkdir` to find out why it is failing. And does your process have write permissions to `/var/log`?

Comment: @kaylum u pointed something I wasn't thinking abt the return value is -1 I m calling the function from mysql client with sudo

Comment: Call `perror()` to get a more detailed error description.

Comment: Errno is 13, I think it permissions denied. I trying to get some more info for now

Comment: Okay, the errno is 13 clearly its permission denied so the UDF cannot create a directory, so I think the question I should be asking is, how can I get mysql to run the function with the right permission